# How to convert a dictionary to a table?

Tags: dictionary, datatables, dolphindb

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
d = {'address': [3, 4], 'ip': ['192.168.0.3', '192.168.0.4'], 'enable': [true, true] ,'frequency': [25, 25], 'gear': [1, 1],'connected': [false, false],'timeout':[false, false], 'update_time': ['2022-10-20 19:59:15.943352', '2022-10-20 19:59:37.827025']}
```

Now I want to convert it to a table, how can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try DolphinDB function `transpose`.

```
t=transpose(d)
```

Output:

```
update_time timeout connected   frequency   gear    ip  enable  address
2022-10-20 19:59:15.943352  false   false   25  1   192.168.0.3 true    3
2022-10-20 19:59:37.827025  false   false   25  1   192.168.0.4 true    4
```